# STM32 HSE unstable frequency

Tags: stm32, sampling, cmsis

I'm trying to run my Nucleo f401re on 80mhz from HSE

```cpp
int F4xxx::clockInit(int pllM, int pllN, int pllP, int pllQ)
{
    enableHse();

    //FLASH
    CLEAR_BIT(FLASH->ACR, FLASH_ACR_PRFTEN);
    FLASH->ACR&= ~FLASH_ACR_LATENCY;
    FLASH->ACR |= FLASH_ACR_LATENCY_5WS | FLASH_ACR_ICEN | FLASH_ACR_DCEN|FLASH_ACR_PRFTEN;

    //set HSE as PLL source
    RCC->PLLCFGR = RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLSRC_HSE;
    //
    RCC->CR &= ~(RCC_CR_PLLON); //disable PLL before changes
    //

    RCC->PLLCFGR = pllM|(pllN<<6)|(((pllP>>1)-1)<<16)|RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLSRC_HSE|(pllQ<<24);
    RCC->CR|=RCC_CR_PLLON;
    while(!(RCC->CR&RCC_CR_PLLRDY));

    RCC->CFGR &= ~(RCC_CFGR_HPRE);  //Prescaler 1
    RCC->CFGR |= RCC_CFGR_HPRE_DIV1; //AHB = SYSCLK/1


    //APB2 Prescaler 2
    RCC->CFGR &= ~(RCC_CFGR_PPRE2);
    RCC->CFGR |= RCC_CFGR_PPRE2_DIV1;  //APB2 /1

    RCC->CFGR &= ~(RCC_CFGR_PPRE1);
    RCC->CFGR|=RCC_CFGR_PPRE1_DIV1; // APB1 /2

    RCC->CFGR &= ~RCC_CFGR_SW; // reset SW0, SW1.
    RCC->CFGR |= RCC_CFGR_SW_PLL;
    RCC->CR|=RCC_CR_PLLON;

    while((RCC->CFGR & RCC_CFGR_SWS)!=RCC_CFGR_SWS_PLL); // wait for switching to PLL (while PLL is not used as system clock)

    // for power saving
    RCC->CR &= ~(RCC_CR_HSION);

    return 0;
}

void F4xxx::enableHse()
{
    // for control MCO2 (PC9): (freq=SYSCLK/5)
    RCC->AHB1ENR|=RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOCEN;
    GPIOC->MODER&=~GPIO_MODER_MODE9;
    GPIOC->MODER|=GPIO_MODER_MODE9_1;
    GPIOC->OSPEEDR|=GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR9;
    RCC->CFGR|=RCC_CFGR_MCO2PRE;

    RCC->CR |= (RCC_CR_HSEON); //Enable HSE
    while( !(RCC->CR & RCC_CR_HSERDY) ) {}; //ready to start HSE
}
```

and then call it like this:

```cpp
f4.clockInit(8, 336, 2, 7);
```

But my logic analyzer show that the frequency is unstable
[image]

The peaks with level=1 have width^-1 = 16 mhz
But the peaks with level=0 have width^-1 = 8 mhz and 5.33 mhz

What could cause such an unstable frequency?

Comment: What is your sampling frequency?

Comment: take a good oscilloscope and the measure.

Comment: @Tagli the issue seems to disappear after clean-build-run again

Comment: It's quite unlikely that it was fixed with a fresh build. That would only explain it if it was a software problem in the first place. However, i cannot image any software related reason why it would show the described behavior. – You have't answered the question regarding the sampling frequency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, your logic analyzer screenshot is from the Saleae software. Unless you have one of the latest models which uses USB 3, I guess your sampling frequency is limited to 24 MHz max. This is also the case for FX2 based cheap clones. Basically, you need USB 3 *OR* Internal Buffer Memory *OR* ability to sample reduced number of channels, like 3 or so in order to sample faster than 24 MHz.

You didn't tell your sampling frequency, but based on the available info, I assume that it's limited to 24 MHz. Nyquist Sampling Theorem states that you need to sample at least 2 times faster than the signal you measure. So, for a 16 MHz signal you need at least 32 MHz sampling rate. At lower sampling frequencies, you observe a phenomena called *aliasing*, where the signal you measure seems to have a lower frequency.

Keep it in mind that 32 MHz is the theoretical minimum and you still may (and probably will) observe distortions in the signal. For analog signals, x10 or x20 sampling rates are generally used. For digital signal like you measure, x4 is probably fine.

Not long ago, I had to debug USB Full Speed bus (12 MHz) with a Saleae clone. Using 24 MHz sampling rate sometimes worked and sometimes didn't. When it didn't, I hit the button and tried my chance again...

So, you probably don't have an issue at all. You are just unable to measure your signal correctly because of the limitation of your equipment. When you repeat your measurements, you will probably have the same sampling issues from time to time.

Comment: I use Saleae clone. They promise to capture signals up to 100MHz